# Killing field and vector field type

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, vector-fields

The Killing field condition can be defined as;

$$\mathcal{L}_{X}g=0$$

for a metric $g$ and vector field $X$. In this case does it matter the type ($X^{\alpha}$ or $X_{\alpha}$) of the $X$ used in this equation? Or for instance if it's given as $X_{\alpha}$ do I have to convert it to $X^{\alpha}$ ?

Because in all of the Lie Derivative equations $X^{\alpha}$ is used.

Comment: By definition, the components of vector fields $X$ have index up. If people use a lower index, then it is an abuse of notation.

Comment: @peek-a-boo So if someone gives me $X_{\alpha}$, I have to change its type right ?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Although using lower indices can be abuse of notation, for Lie derivative of metric, we have the identity: $\mathscr{L}_Xg_{ab}=0\implies \nabla_aX_b+\nabla_bX_a=0$. So, in this case you may work with lower indices

Comment: @KP99 hmm but I also saw that equation...maybe the two equations are the same when we raise indices